# Is there a way in Javascript to turn links in an HTML document into clickable links?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way in pure Javascript to turn links in an HTML document into clickable links? I do not want to use regex to solve this problem.

Let's say I have this list in an HTML5 doc:

```
<pre>
http://www.test.com
http://www.example.com
http://nicelink.com
</pre>
```

And I want it to automatically turn into this when the page is loaded:

```
<pre>
<a href="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
<a href="http://nicelink.com">http://nicelink.com</a>
</pre>
```

What would the vanilla JS code look like if I put a script in the header? Something looping through the HTML code and replacing the lines I suppose but I cannot write it in JS.

Signy

Comment: what you have do far?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this:

```
var str = $('pre').html().trim();
var ar = str.split('\n');
var html = "";
for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
{
    html +="<a href='"+ar[i]+"'>"+ar[i]+"</a><br>";
}
console.log(html);
$('body').html(html);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/hyzdxdnp/)

Comment: Looking pretty good. Is this really the ultimate answer? Does it cover all the cases? I understand that URIs can be complex in their syntax.